# Populate a select list ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm busy with an ASP.NET Core MVC application, and I'm trying to populate a drop down list. I've created a view model and I have added a method to my `StoresController` that returns a list of stores that I want to display in a dropdown. I've been working off some online tutorials as I'm very new to asp.

View model:

```
public class StoreListViewModel
{
    public List<StoreList> StoreList { get; set; } = new List<StoreList>();
}

public class StoreList
{
    public string StoreId { get; set; } = null!;
    public string StoreName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

`StoresController`:

```
public IActionResult LoadStoreList()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var storeList = new StoreListViewModel().StoreList.Select
                        (x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.StoreId, Text = x.StoreName }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Stores = storeList;
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

I'm trying to use `ViewBag` to call my `LoadStoreList()` method.

```
<select name="storeList" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Stores, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
```

When I load my page I get the following error

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')

The page I need the dropdown list on is my `CreateUser.cshtml` which is bound to my `UserModel` and has a `UsersController`. The method I have created for listing the stores is in my `StoresController` which is bound to my `StoresModel`. So I'm not sure if that's causing the issue.

I've been battling with this for days, if someone could help me get this working or show me a better method, that would be great.

*Edit

The **UserIndex()** method is the first method that fires when my users page opens, do I call the **LoadStoreList()** method from there ?

**UserController**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UsersIndex()
{
      return _context.UsersView != null ? 
                  View(await _context.UsersView.ToListAsync()) :
                  Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Users'  is null.");
}
```

Comment: Hi @AlexJames, why you use `new StoreListViewModel().StoreList`? From your code StoreList just an empty list model and it does not contain any value, that is why you get the `Value cannot be null.` error. Where is the data you want to get from? From database?

Comment: Hi @Rena I'm trying to get the data from the database using ef core.

Comment: Hi @AlexJames, check the whole working demo below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to use ViewBag to call my LoadStoreList() method.

ViewBag cannot be used to call any method. You just need set value for `ViewBag` in the method which renders your show dropdownlist's page.

From your description, you said the page you need the dropdown list on is `CreateUser.cshtml`.  Assume that you render the `CreateUser.cshtml` page by using `CreateUser` action.

CreateUser.cshtml:

```
<select name="storeList" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Stores, "Value", "Text"))"></select>
```

Controller:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly YourDbcontext _context;
    public YourController(YourDbcontext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CreateUser（）
    {
        var storeList = _context.StoreLists.Select
            (x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.StoreId , Text = x.StoreName }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Stores = storeList;
        return View();
    }
}
```

YourDbcontext should be something like:

```
public class YourDbcontext: DbContext
{
    public YourDbcontext(DbContextOptions<MvcProjContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<StoreList> StoreLists{ get; set; } 

}
```

Comment: Hi @Rena, yeah the CreateUser() method is the first to load for that page. I already have code in that method that i need, so can't replace it. Can I not just call the **LoadStoreList()** method after that ?

Comment: Hi @AlexJames, you could ony call `LoadStoreList()` in the  `CreateUser` method.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use viewbag for storing list data. Make your view page model including List, for example:

```
public class UserCreationViewModel{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Any other properties....
     public List<StoreList> StoreList { get; set; }
}
```

in your controller YourController:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateUser()
{
    var storeList = new StoreListViewModel().StoreList.Select
                    (x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.StoreId, Text = x.StoreName }).ToList();

    UserCreationViewModel model=new UserCreationViewModel{
      StoreList = storeList
    };    

 return View("createUserViewName", model);
 }
```

in createUserViewName:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StoreId", new SelectList(Model.StoreList, "StoreId", "StoreName"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

or

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.StoreId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.StoreList, "StoreId", "StoreName"))">
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
</select>
```